# connect office 365 subscription with azure AD

Tags: azure, office365

sorry for my english...
I have a subscription to Office 365 (E3 Plan) with domain mycompany.onmicropsoft.com and another subscription to Windows Azure (myotherdomain.onmicrosoft.com).
At the moment on Azure, into WAAD I don't see the Office 365 users and vice versa, but I'd like to have centralized management by azure.
how can I do to associate the Windows Azure subscription to Office365 subscription so that I can manage Office365 users with Windows Azure. 
Thank You
Michele